# Google App Engine dynamic backends are not stopped

Tags: google-app-engine

(If this is not a question for SO, I will be gladly moved elsewhere)

I have a GAE backend that I want to start regularly with cron. With the help of other questions from SO, I set up backends.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<backends>
 <backend name="myBackend">
   <class>B1</class>
   <instances>1</instances>
<options>
     <dynamic>true</dynamic>
   </options>
 </backend>
</backends>
```

and my cron.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/doHardStuff</url>
    <description>doing long running stuff</description>
    <schedule>every 3 hours</schedule>
    <target>myBackend</target>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

And I upload it using `mvn-gae` (I am writing everything in java with maven) with goals `gae:deploy gae:backends-list gae:backends-update`

Everything loads fine and the long running stuff is done, **however**. Even after finishing everything, the dynamic backend still runs and eats my daily backend quota. I can see `_ah/stop` request in logs after the servlet finishes its job; however the backend still runs after that.

If I **stop** it manually in engine web console in Main -> Backends -> Start/Stop, it stops eating my quota, however, it **won't** run at a given time in cron and the cron job will fail.

What should I do? I want the backend to *start at the given time* and *stop when the request is over and the machine is idle*. I don't want it running at a different time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as it's supposed to. Dynamic backends are always "started" in the backends tab in the dashboard, which just means they can get requests and start instances if needed. This doesn't consume any quota.

When the backend gets a request it starts an instance using `/_ah/start/` and consumes quota. When it doesn't have any requests to serve for some minutes it stops the instance with an `/_ah/stop/` request.

To figure out if the backend instance is still running, change to the instances tab and select the backend "version".

Note that dynamic backends have a 15 minutes quota penalty, which is probably why the quota usage is higher than expected.

> For dynamic backends, billing ends fifteen minutes after the last
>   request has finished processing.

http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: Yes, I have missed that part. That was it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it takes them 15 minutes to be stopped, according to some pages online.

This seems possible, I will try it.